# Solutions to communicate with spring boot sseemitter from wpf client

Tags: c#, spring-boot, servicestack, server-sent-events

I have one wpf application and a spring boot application, and want to use server sent events to notify the wpf application when something occurs.

I googled "c# sse client" or ".net sse client" and something like that, found "[servicestack](https://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-client)" is very close to what I mean, However, the client seems need specific server side implementation of its own instead of spring boot sseemitter.

The Microsoft also have a similar tech "SignalR", but that is .net related.

I also want to use websocket which both wpf and spring boot have support, but that will involve more development effort.

Does someone have good idea, thanks!

```
==========================================
```

Another solution is to use cefsharp to build a js client?